How to dynamically change CherryPy configuration
I'm using CherryPy to develop a local application.  When the program starts I use the staticdir tools to setup the initial file location.
   self.conf [ '/images' ] = {
      'tools.staticdir.on': True,
      'tools.staticdir.dir': startDir
   }
   cherrypy.config.update ( self.conf )

This works and my files are served properly.  Later the user can navigate through the folders and pick a different directory to work from.  I update the config and pass it to update but the new directory is not served.
   self.conf [ '/images' ] = {
      'tools.staticdir.on': True,
      'tools.staticdir.dir': newDir
   }
   cherrypy.config.update ( self.conf )

This does not work.
I've also tried
cherrypy.lib.static.staticdir( section="images" , dir=self.path , debug=True )

which does not work.
How can I dynamically change which directory is being served?
